# How to add a URL or Zoom Meeting ID to Google Calendar via API

Tags: google-calendar-api, zoom-sdk

I am writing a complex integration between Zoom and Google calendar - I can't really use their out of the box solutions. I have the Google Calendar API working fine (CRUD) but I don't see a way to add a Zoom meeting ID or a **top level** link via the API. It appears the Google Calendar product provides a place for Zoom meeting information - I just cannot see how to create it.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like using event.description is the only way to do this - inline links.  The other top level methods pertain to google products, like hangouts, only.

Comment: Did you find any solution for adding Zoom link as conference data in GCal events using Google calendar API?

Comment: I created a feature request for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167533577

Comment: Google is doing what it can to make it hard to add Zoom links - they want people to use their Meet product.  The description field is where the Zoom App itself creates its meeting links. Don't expect that google will help much here unless antitrust investigators force the issue..!

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but for everyone looking for something similar you can do it using the [conferenceData](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) param.

The minimal working example is something like this:

```
conferenceData: {
conferenceSolution: {
  key: { type: "addOn" },
  name: "Zoom",
},
entryPoints: [
  {
    entryPointType: "video",
    passcode: "4gnZXJ",
    uri: "https://zoom.us/j/93831668388?pwd=UHRqU0VwMjF3d1B0VXU5bFBRYWIxdz09",
  },
],
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to send the `conferenceDataVersion` query param with the value of `1` in order to take the `conferenceData` [Docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)